# Where does No. 6 go with his car in the title sequence?

Tags: film-location, the-prisoner

The title/opening sequence of The Prisoner has McGoohan's character - No. 6 - drive his car into some parking garage near the British Parliament building (IIANM). Was that garage really located there in the late 1960s? If so, what occupied the surrounding buildings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Abingdon Street Car Park, London

[image]

> This location represents the vehicle entrance to the offices of Number Six's bosses. It appears before and after the resignation scene in the opening sequence where Number Six's Lotus is seen driving down (and later back up) the entrance ramp. The car park ramp features again in "Many Happy Returns" and "Do Not Forsake Me Oh My Darling" when Number Six returns to London and visits his former colleagues.
>
> IN REALITY: Abingdon Street Car Park is located a stone's throw from the Houses of Parliament in Westminster, London SW1. Only the exterior of the car-park was shown in the series, as the interior car park sequences were filmed at another location, under Park Lane.
>
> <sup>[Source](https://www.theunmutual.co.uk/abcarpark.htm)</sup>

---

**Abingdon Street**

> Only four houses survived the bombing of the 2nd World War which exposed the Jewel Tower behind. The remains of a medieval quay were discovered during demolition of the remaining houses. **In 1963–6 Abingdon Street Garden was created. Beneath is an underground car park.**
>
> <sup>[Source](https://www.britainexpress.com/London/Abingdon-Street.htm)</sup>